# How to build a project using devops pipelines and deploy it to Azure Web Service using a release pipeline?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, devops

I have an ASP.NET Core/.NET 5 based project that I want to build and deploy it to Azure Web Service using the pipelines in devops.

My solution has many projects. However, the `MyProject.Web.dll` is the only startup project.

Since my solution has many projects, I'll need to find a way to generate a single zip file to be consumed by the release pipeline. So here is how I created the build pipeline using the classic editor.

1. Restore. I only added `NuGet.config` to rebuild using a custom repository.

[image]

2. Build step (no change)
   [image]
3. In the publish step I added an output folder `-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app` I also unchecked the `Zip published projects` option to force generating a single `.zip` folder for the release pipeline. Also, I unchecked `Add project's folder name to publish path` Not sure if this should be check or not. But the expected output here is that all the dll will be in the `app` folder.
   [image]
4. Now that everything was built is in the `app` folder, I added the Archive task to archive the app folder by generating `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` (for example 10.zip)
   [image]
5. Lastly, I published my artifact to Azure Pipelines to be picked up later by the release pipeline. This task picks up the generated `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` file and pushes it to the pipeline

[image]

When I manually download/extract the produced .zip file, all the files are located inside the `app` folder. so my startup project is in `app/ProjectName.Web.dll`

Now, in my release pipeline, I have a single deploy task. Its a `Deploy Azure App Service`

As you can see my Startup command is `dotnet ProjectName.Web.dll`. I may have to change directory somehow `cd app` to run the project correctly. If that is the case, how would I do that?

[image]

Both pipelines succeed and the project is deployed. However, when I visit my project's URL I get this error `:( Application Error`

[image]

What am I missing here? How can I successfully deploy and run my project?

The container crash logs in Azure shows `The application 'MyProject.Web.dll' does not exist.` I am guessing it's because the output should be in the main directory not inside the `app` folder.

Here are the logs from my container crash.

```
Container myproject_0_9d3da1b9 couldn't be started: Logs = 2022-01-15T04:46:24.882289338Z   _____                               
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882306639Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882324839Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882328339Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882331139Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882334039Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882336739Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882339439Z 
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882341939Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882344539Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882347139Z ASP .NETCore Version: 5.0.9
2022-01-15T04:46:24.882349839Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2022-01-15T04:46:25.095591263Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -userStartupCommand 'dotnet MyProject.Web.dll' 
2022-01-15T04:46:25.182945407Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2022-01-15T04:46:25.182962308Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2022-01-15T04:46:25.182965708Z Build Operation ID: 70ce914f-2a41-4def-90ef-d3122eed4ca3
2022-01-15T04:46:26.367247139Z 
2022-01-15T04:46:26.367321440Z Agent extension disabled
2022-01-15T04:46:26.367380141Z Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime 
2022-01-15T04:46:26.815282401Z DotNet Runtime 5.0Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2022-01-15T04:46:27.448555687Z Running user provided startup command...
2022-01-15T04:46:27.497807631Z Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
2022-01-15T04:46:27.497824732Z Possible reasons for this include:
2022-01-15T04:46:27.497828732Z   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
2022-01-15T04:46:27.497832032Z       The application 'MyProject.Web.dll' does not exist.
2022-01-15T04:46:27.498326838Z   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2022-01-15T04:46:27.498332338Z       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
2022-01-15T04:46:27.498335738Z       Install a .NET SDK from:
2022-01-15T04:46:27.498339238Z         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**UPDATED**
As per comments below, I changed how I deploy my project to use yml file instead. Also, I created a new "Azure App Service for Containers" to deploy docker image to. Here is the YML file that I am using which seems to build and deploy correctly but the app is not running. However, this time around I do do not have logs in azure to tell me what could be causing the issue

```yaml
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'connection id'
  subscriptionName: 'name-of-the-subscription'
  imageRepository: 'name-of-image'
  containerRegistry: 'myregistryname.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(subscriptionName)'
        appName: 'myapp-name'
        containers: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
```

Comment: You should really be using YAML pipelines -- classic build/release pipelines are legacy technology really only intended for backwards compatibility at this point.

Comment: @DanielMann how would that solve my problem? If your answer require the use of plain yml file, I would love to see how.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, which is why it's a comment, not an answer. However, it's easier to help people diagnose problems with YAML pipelines because you can just post the entire pipeline in your question and it can easily be scanned for issues. As it stands, you're posting screenshots and anyone trying to help you would have to play 20 questions because the problem might be something very simple in a step that you're not including a screenshot of. On that note, including the output for the deployment step would also be useful.

Comment: @DanielMann as per your instruction, I created a yml file and posted it. please check my revised question. The pipeline seems to build and deploy correctly. but the app wont run. I checked the image is published on the registry correctly

Comment: Does the container run locally? Your YAML and your classic pipelines are doing different things. The YAML is trying to run a container. The classic pipeline is trying to deploy an application directly, outside of a container.

Comment: @DanielMann correct. I did not know how to do it other way. currently, the build process creates a docker image, stores it in a private registry and then it deploy it to the Azure Web Service. I am not sure how I can run it locally